# Error when compiling Linux kernel 3.2 for ARM

Tags: linux, gcc, linux-kernel, qemu

I am following this tutorial to compile Linux kernel 3.2 for ARM and emulate with QEMU:

https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/compile-linux-kernel-3-2-for-arm-and-emulate-with-qemu/

I am following the below steps:

1. `wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.2.tar.bz2`
2. `tar xjf linux-3.2.tar.bz2`
3. `export ARCH=arm`
4. `export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-`
5. `cd linux-3.2`
6. `make vexpress_defconfig`
7. `make all`
8. `cd ..`
9. `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static init.c -o init`
10. `echo init|cpio -o --format=newc > initramfs`
11. `qemu-system-arm -M vexpress-a9 -kernel linux-3.2/arch/arm/boot/zImage -initrd initramfs -serial stdio -append "console=tty1"`

My problem is when I try step 7 (make all), this problem happens:

```
include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:94:30: fatal error: linux/compiler-gcc5.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/home/ramy/QEMU_Learn/kernel/linux-3.2/./Kbuild:35: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
Makefile:985: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
```

I am working Ubuntu operating system, and I am using Linaro tool chain to compile the kernel.

I have also checked the PATH variable and here is the result:

```
$ printenv | grep PATH

XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ramy/gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_3-2016q1/bin
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
```

Comment: What is your cross compiler? What is your linaro version? The post linked https://balau82.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/compile-linux-kernel-3-2-for-arm-and-emulate-with-qemu/ was from 2012, so use linaro from 2012 year to compile 3.2 kernel, not newer. The gcc version in your linaro is too new to be able to compile so old linux kernel. Or try newer kernel (but commands from this old blog may not work)

Comment: Linux kernel version 3.2 was released before gcc version 5 existed. Kernel version 3.2.81 has this header.

Comment: Thanks, but how to get Linaro with gcc-4 in Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your kernel version (3.2.0) is too old and not compatible with used gcc (gcc-5). You may use gcc-4 to compile kernel, or use newer kernel version.

Your kernel has special include in `linux/compiler-gcc.h` header
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/compiler-gcc.h?v=3.2#L91

```
 91 #define __gcc_header(x) #x
 92 #define _gcc_header(x) __gcc_header(linux/compiler-gcc##x.h)
 93 #define gcc_header(x) _gcc_header(x)
 94 #include gcc_header(__GNUC__)
```

It will include different files for different gcc versions (**GNUC** is major version of gcc). It supports gcc-3 and gcc-4, but not gcc-5:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/?v=3.2

```
C file  compiler-gcc.h  3705 bytes
C file  compiler-gcc3.h 631 bytes
C file  compiler-gcc4.h 2073 bytes
C file  compiler-intel.h    746 bytes
C file  compiler.h  8628 bytes
```

You may try to rewrite `compiler-gcc4.h` to `compiler-gcc5.h`, but you should understand how to do this. You may not just copy gcc4 to gcc5, there will incorrect macro.

The `compiler-gcc5.h` was added only to linux kernel version 3.18: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h?v=3.18 (not in 3.17 http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/compiler-gcc5.h?v=3.17)

Older linaro compiler (before gcc-5) is https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/4.9-2016.02/

And according to JJ Hakala comment, there is the compiler-gcc5 header in last version of 3.2.* kernel, the 3.2.81: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.2.81.tar.gz - just change wget command and tar xjf to this version and  retry.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how to get Linaro with gcc-4 in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Ramy, JJHakala says that 3.2.81 kernel has the header; try it (change wget command address to https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.2.81.tar.gz). Linaro before gcc-5 is 4.9-2016.02 at  https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/4.9-2016.02/.

Comment: I prefer to use the old kernel, because I need to follow the commands from the old post, I am worried that some commands might not work with the new kernel

Comment: Ramy, this 3.2.81 is the same old kernel with several fixes/bugs backported. Just update minor versions in scripts.

Comment: Thanks osgx, I did that, but I faced some troubles when building the new kernel. It will be better to post the error in a new question, correct ?

Comment: Ramy, I'm not sure. You may try older gcc.